# My scanner class java code has a exception that is a error

Tags: java

I get this error when running my code, please help.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

I would appreciate any fixes you could provide to the code overall.

When I input data like weight in this case, it is full of mistakes and it's annoying.

```
package howto;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Howto {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        double weightkg [] = new double [30];

        double weightkgEndOfMonth [] = new double [30];

        String name [] = new String [30];

        double weightDifference [] = new double[30];



        for (int i = 0; i<31; i++)

        {

            System.out.println("Input name: ");

            String scanner1 = sc1.nextLine();



            name [i] = scanner1;



            System.out.println("Input weight: ");

            double scanner2 = sc2.nextDouble();



            if(!sc1.hasNextDouble())

            {

                System.out.println("Invalid Weight!. Start Again");

            } else

            {

                weightkg[i] =  scanner2;

            }



            System.out.println("Name: " + name[i]);

            System.out.println("weight : " + weightkg[i]);



        }



        for (int i = 0; i<31; i++)

        {



            System.out.println("Input weight at the end of month: ");

            double scanner2 = sc2.nextDouble();



            if(!sc1.hasNextDouble())

            {

                System.out.println("Invalid Weight!. Start Again");

            } else

            {

                weightkgEndOfMonth[i] =  scanner2;

            }



            weightDifference [i] = weightkg[i] - weightkgEndOfMonth[i];



            if(weightDifference[i]>2.5)

            {

                System.out.println("Student with a weight difference greater than 2.5kg: " + name[i]);

                System.out.println("Weight difference: " + weightDifference[i]);

                System.out.println("Rise");

            }



            if(weightDifference[i]> -2.5)

            {

                System.out.println("Student with a weight difference greater than 2.5kg: " + name[i]);

                System.out.println("Weight difference: " + weightDifference[i]);

                System.out.println("Fall");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
run:
Input name: 
Test
Input weight: 
90
10
Name: Test
weight : 90.0
Input name: 
Input weight: 
Test1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at howto.Howto.main(Howto.java:45)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Comment: You don't need two scanners

Comment: `nextDouble` will leave the new line in the buffer, which is getting read by the next `nextLine` statement.  After each `nextDouble` call, add a call `nextLine` so the newline is consumed

Comment: I tried this and it gave me 3 spaces after every line to input instead of the 1 extra i was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues which stand out...

First...

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You don't need multiple scanners, they are reading from the same stream anyway, better to use just one and reduce the complexity.

Next...

```
String scanner1 = sc1.nextLine();
name [i] = scanner1;

System.out.println("Input weight: ");

double scanner2 = sc2.nextDouble();
if(!sc1.hasNextDouble())
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Weight!. Start Again");

} else
{
    weightkg[i] =  scanner2;
}
```

When using `nextDouble`, the buffer still contains a newline marker, meaning that the next time you use `nextLine`, it will return a blank `String` and move on.

Also, `hasNextDouble` seems to be waiting for data, but you've already read the `double` value from the buffer, leaving the dangling new line.  In my test, this was causing issues with the program waiting for more input.

I "solved" the basic problem by doing something like this...

```
String scanner1 = sc1.nextLine();
name [i] = scanner1;

System.out.println("Input weight: ");

double scanner2 = sc1.nextDouble();
weightkg[i] =  scanner2;
sc1.nextLine();
```

Now this "will" work, but it's not the best solution. A "different" approach might be to read the weight in as a `String` and attempt to parse it as a `double`, this gives you the chance to trap the invalid input and handle it in a more appropriate manner, for example...

```
System.out.println("Input name: ");

String scanner1 = sc1.nextLine();

name[i] = scanner1;

boolean done = false;
double weight = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Input weight: ");
    String input = sc1.nextLine();
    try {
        weight = Double.parseDouble(input);
        done = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("!! Invalid value");
    }
} while (!done);
weightkg[i] = weight;

System.out.println("Name: " + name[i]);

System.out.println("weight : " + weightkg[i]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have some logical mistakes in your code. after every line i mention them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HowTo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in); // you need only 1 scanner
    double weightkg[] = new double[30];
    double weightkgEndOfMonth[] = new double[30];
    String name[] = new String[30];
    double weightDifference[] = new double[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { // need to iterate from 0 index to 29
      System.out.print("Input name: ");
      String scanner1 = sc1.nextLine();
      name[i] = scanner1;
      System.out.print("Input weight: ");
      if (!sc1.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Weight!. Start Again");
      } else {
        weightkg[i] = sc1.nextDouble();// if it has double then read it 
      }
      System.out.println("Name: " + name[i]);
      System.out.println("weight : " + weightkg[i]);
      sc1.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {// need to iterate from 0 index to 29
      System.out.println("Input weight at the end of month: ");
      if (!sc1.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Weight!. Start Again");
      } else {
        weightkgEndOfMonth[i] = sc1.nextDouble();// read double here 
      }
      weightDifference[i] =weightkgEndOfMonth[i]- weightkg[i] ;// weight difference is (final weight- initial weight)
      if (weightDifference[i] > 2.5) {
        System.out.println("Student with a weight difference greater than 2.5kg: " + name[i]);
        System.out.println("Weight difference: " + weightDifference[i]);
        System.out.println("Rise");
      }
      if (weightDifference[i] < -2.5) {// fall if weight less than 2.5
        System.out.println("Student with a weight difference greater than 2.5kg: " + name[i]);
        System.out.println("Weight difference: " + weightDifference[i]);
        System.out.println("Fall");
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Now it is working fine.